# Input field with floating label design and mask

Tags: react-native

In the app I'm building I want to use in a form input fields with Floating style label design

I tested some libraries that have this type of field and I considered [NativeBase.io](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#floating-label-headref) better, but in this I found no way to put mask content, and in none of the other libraries either.

So, is there a way to put the content mask in this field? Or is there a library that allows me to create an Input with Floating Label style design and content mask?

What I would like to do is something like this if Input was in html, but in React-native it does not work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { 
  Text, 
  Form, 
  Item, 
  Label, 
  Input 
} from 'native-base';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form style={{ width: 340 }}>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Tel</Label>
            <Input data-mask="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask-selectionfocus="true" />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

I tried to attach the field of a library that allows the creation of fields with mask inside the floatingLabel but without success

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { 
  Text, 
  Form, 
  Item, 
  Label, 
  Input 
} from 'native-base';
import TextInputMask from 'react-native-text-input-mask';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form style={{ width: 340 }}>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Tel</Label>
            <TextInputMask
              refInput={ref => { this.input = ref }}
              onChangeText={(formatted, extracted) => {
                console.log(formatted) // +1 (123) 456-78-90
                console.log(extracted) // 1234567890
              }}
              mask={"+1 ([000]) [000] [00] [00]"}
            />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

The [snack](https://snack.expo.io/Skmfv4Zn-) is having some problem with the [TextInputMask](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask) library and it does not work, however it works independently here locally:

[image]

Comment: When you say you want an input mask, you mean that you'd like to format the input a certain way, right? Such as a phone number formatted at (858) 555-1212. If so, I find it unbelievable that you wouldn't be able to mask your input and also have a floating label. Why do you think it's not possible? Can you setup a demo?

Comment: @ChrisGeirman I've added a demo code

Comment: I tried creating a snack, but it fails to install the text-input-mask plugin. Might just be my internet connection, which sucks today. If you can get a snack setup and working, I'll have another look, but so far it seems like what you're doing should work. https://snack.expo.io/HyiMuTl3W

Comment: If I were you, I'd try isolating each to work by itself, then once I had both working independently, then I'd merge them.

Comment: They work independently

Comment: Prove it on snack

Comment: The snack has some problem that does not run with the TextInputMask library however here locally it works as shown above